# How to split string between different chars

Tags: c#, string, split

I am having trouble splitting a string. I want to split only the words between 2 different chars:

```
 string text = "the dog :is very# cute";
```

How can I grab only the words, *is very*, between the `:` and `#` chars?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method with `params char[]`;

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified Unicode character array.

```
string text = "the dog :is very# cute";
string str = text.Split(':', '#')[1]; // [1] means it selects second part of your what you split parts of your string. (Zero based)
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/gVnrwN).

You can use it any number of you want.

Comment: Note: This will also catch strings between characters that are not in the order specified in the question, for example `is` in `"This #is# a :test#."`

Answer (score 8):

That's not really a split at all, so using `Split` would create a bunch of strings that you don't want to use. Simply get the index of the characters, and use `SubString`:

```
int startIndex = text.IndexOf(':');
int endIndex = test.IndexOf('#', startIndex);
string very = text.SubString(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex - 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

use this code

```
var varable = text.Split(':', '#')[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b873y76a.aspx) of [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.split.aspx) takes a `params char[]` - you can use any number of characters to split on:

```
string isVery = text.Split(':', '#')[1];
```

Note that I am using that overload and am taking the *second* item from the returned array.

However, as @Guffa noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797608/1583), what you are doing is not really a split, but extracting a specific sub string, so using his approach may be better.

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(":(.+?)#");
Console.WriteLine(regex.Match("the dog :is very# cute").Groups[1].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:

```
    [Test]
    public void split()
    {
        string text = "the dog :is very# cute"  ;

        // how can i grab only the words:"is very" using the (: #) chars. 
        var actual = text.Split(new [] {':', '#'});

        Assert.AreEqual("is very", actual[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.IndexOf` and `String.Substring`

```
string text = "the dog :is very# cute"  ;
int colon = text.IndexOf(':') + 1;
int hash = text.IndexOf('#', colon);
string result = text.Substring(colon , hash - colon);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.split.aspx) twice. Get the string to the right of the first separator. Then, using the result, get the string to the left of second separator.

```
string text = "the dog :is very# cute"; 
string result = text.Split(":")[1] // is very# cute";
                    .Split("#")[0]; // is very
```

It avoids playing around with indexes and regex which makes it more readable IMO.